# Manifest-based ETW provider - Decoding File Locations

Tags: c++, winapi, etw

I am trying to add ETW tracing to a DLL (written in C++) I have created. I am using the manifest-based method.

Tracing is working, but it appears I need to set the "Decoding File Locations" in the manifest to an absolute path before building the DLL.

The DLL could be deployed anywhere though, so the decoding path varies depending on the user's installation.

Is there a way around this at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add references and links where appropriate (e.g. the *manifest-based method*, documentation on *"Decoding File Locations"*).

Comment: @IInspectable he refers to this entry in a manifest: **<provider guid="{538cbbad-4877-4eb2-b26e-7caee8f0f8cb}" message="$(string.ProviderName)" messageFileName="%SystemRoot%\system32\fdphost.dll" name="Microsoft-Windows-FunctionDiscoveryHost"** the messageFileName requires a fixed location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installing the provider, be sure to set the switches `/resourceFilePath` and `/messageFilePath` to the path of your DLL. This will override the decoding file locations specified in the manifest that the DLL was built with.

e.g.:

```
wevtutil.exe /resourceFilePath:path_to_DLL /messageFilePath:path_to_DLL im path_to_manifest
```

Comment: Note that this method only works with Windows 7 or higher.